# Jquery Impromptu > Go to URL

Tags: jquery, impromptu

After as much research as possible I don't have a working solution to what seems a simple problem.

I would like to use [Jquery Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php).

Simple action.

1. Click on Logout – `<a class="link" href="javascript:;" onclick="logout(1); ">Logout</a>`
2. Prompt 'Are you sure - Yes / No'
3. If Cancel, Nothing happens. If True go to a url 'logoutscript.php'.

I cannot get my thoughts to work and though I just cannot get my head around it. Any help would be really helpful.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

function removeUser(id){
var txt = 'Are you sure you want to Logout?';

$.prompt(txt,{ 
buttons:{Logout:true, Cancel:false},
callback: function(v,m,f){

<!-- This is wher the problem starts -->

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

 a class="link" href="javascript:;" onclick="removeUser(1); ">Logout</a>
```

Comment: `href="javascript:void(0);"` maybe?

Comment: wow thank you for messing up the edit @zerocrates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

**HTML**

```
<a class="link" href="#" data-id="1">Logout</a>
```

**JS**

```
function removeUser(id) { 
    var txt = 'Are you sure you want to Logout?';
    $.prompt(txt, { 
        buttons: {
            Logout: true, 
            Cancel: false
        }, 
        callback: function(accept) {
            if (accept) {
                window.location = "logoutscript.php";
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

$('a.link').click(function() {
    removeUser($(this).data('id'));
    return false;
});
```

You can as well call the method inline, if you need to.

*For the future: Please provide complete and formatted code. In your list a method is called `logout`, in the code sample `removeUser`, then the code breaks up after an opening curly bracket.*

Comment: Cheers @polarblau. Really appreciate your help. – Paul